# No bean named xxx available

Tags: java, spring

It is a very simple program that has a main class as `JavaLoader`, one interface `Student`. `Student` is implemented by two classes.
I have also made a configuration class. When I instantiate the bean from the main class and call a method on `Samir`. A `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` is thrown.

Main class (`JavaLoader`):

```
package spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
public class JavaLoader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext appContext = new
                AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("StudentConfig.class");

        Student samir = (Student) appContext.getBean("samir", Student.class);
        System.out.println(samir.readsBook());
    }
}
```

`StudentConfig` class:

```
package spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("spring")
public class StudentConfig {

}
```

`Samir` class:

```
package spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("samir")
public class Samir implements Student{
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("history")
    Book book;

    public Samir(Book book){
        this.book = book;
    }
    public String readsBook(){
        return book.readBook();
    }
}
```

The expected output is that the method `samir.readsBook()` on `JavaLoader` should be executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to provide a `Class` instance to the `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` constructor:

```
 new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(StudentConfig.class);
```

note that `StudentConfig.class` is not the same as the string `"StudentConfig.class"`.

Note that `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext` has a string-constructor as well (that's why your code still compiles), but that string is interpreted as a *base package* for auto-scanning rather than the configuration class name.

Comment: It's more that `String` constructor uses the package name so it as well could be 

`new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext("spring")`

Comment: @Alex , now your answer seems ok.